# Fallo al cargar gallery con Masonry y isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Buenas tengo una galería donde muestro elemento con el efecto Masonry y para filtrar el Isotope. Pero tengo un problema. Si cargo la página por primera vez o si hace mucho rato, la galeria sale todo desestructurado, como si no cargase el JavaScript, pero si le doy a un filtro, actualizo la página, etc... funciona de forma perfecta.

**Esto es lo que utilizo como filtros**

```
<section class="gallery" id="galleryWai">
        <div class="containerGallery">
            <div id="menusGallery">
                <div class="barraGallery"></div>
                <h1>Gallery</h1>
                <p>Discover my world</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="menuZonas" id="zonasGalleryWai">
            <div class="lasZonas">
                <ul id="filters">
                    <a class="filter" data-filter=".ferrari"><li class="bordeZonas activaZona" id="ferrari">Ferrari</li></a>
                    <a class="filter" data-filter=".lotus"><li class="bordeZonas" id="lotus">Lotus</li></a>
                    <a class="filter" data-filter=".mclaren"><li class="bordeZonas" id="mclaren">McLaren</li></a>
                    <a class="filter" data-filter=".training"><li class="bordeZonas" id="training">Training</li></a>
                    <a class="filter" data-filter=".scenes"><li id="scenes">Behind the scenes</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

**Luego donde cargo la galería**

```
<section class="galeria" id="galeriaWaiTotal">
        <div class="col-12 espacioModulo">
            <div class="grid" id="mygrid">
                @foreach ($fotos as $item)
                    <div class="grid-item {{ $item->filter }}" data-category="{{ $item->filter }}">
                        <img src="{{ asset("{$item->foto}") }}" alt="" class="">
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

**El script con el que filtro y cargo el masonry**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.pagination').hide();

    // init Isotope
    let $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    filter: '.ferrari',
    getSortData: {
        name: '.ferrari',
        category: '[data-category]'
      },
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: '.grid-item'
      }
  });

  // bind filter button click
  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });

  });
```

Cual puede ser el problema??